# using jquery make loop fadeout change background position fadein

Tags: jquery, loops, fadein

I write this but it don't work, what I need like this http://www.partyhunli.com/Public/uploads/20140812/53e96b0c39033.swf

```
setInterval(function () {
        $('.sub').fadeOut(1000).css('background-position', '0 100%').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).css('background-position', '0 0');
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` are asynchronous. The code you currently have fires `fadeOut` twice, `fadeIn` and your two `css()` calls all at once. `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` have callback functions which you can use instead:

```
$('.sub').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).css('background-position', '0 100%').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).css('background-position', '0 0');
        })
    });
});
```

With this, your code will only progress after the `fadeOut` or `fadeIn` transitions have completed.

Here is a snippet which shows what this does (I've changed the `background-color` rather than `background-position` here).

```js
$('.sub').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#0f0').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
        })
    });
});
```

```css
figure {
  background: #f00;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="sub"></figure>
```

Comment: thank you james, sorry it don't work, what I need it like this effect :http://www.partyhunli.com/Public/uploads/20140812/53e96b0c39033.swf  fadeout + change background + fadein + fadeout + change bankground

Comment: thanks james
finally it works:
---------------------------------------
var loops = function(){
 $('.sub').fadeIn(1500, function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1500, function(){
   $(this).css('background-position', '0 100%').fadeIn(1500, function() {  
    $(this).fadeOut(1500, loops);
    } ) 
  });
    }).css('background-position', '0 0');

 
}


loops();
--------------------------------